# Get certain files from a directory using glob() - PHP

Tags: php, glob

Basically I want to get the files from a directory using `glob()`. The file format are like this:

```
052013.www.test1.com.txt
052014.www.test1.com.txt
062014.www.test1.com.txt
072014.www.test1.com.txt
082014.m.test1.com.txt
092014.test1.com.txt
```

And i would like to only get the file of the curent year (i.e `$_SESSION['year']`) and that has `www` or `m` in it, so here's my function :

```
function get_files(){
    $dir = DOCUMENT_ROOT;
    $hostname = HOST;
    $files = array();
    $scan = glob($dir."{*".$_SESSION['year'].".m.,*".$_SESSION['year'].".www.}".$hostname.".txt", GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_NOCHECK );
    foreach ( $scan as $file ) {
      $files[] = $file;
    }
    return $files;
}
```

The issue here is when it doesn't found any file that has for example `www` it returns this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/stats/082014.m.test1.com.txt
    [1] => /var/www/stats/*2014.www.test1.com.txt
)
```

What's the mistake I'm making in my function here? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GLOB_NOCHECK - Return the search pattern if no files matching it were found

You can just remove the GLOB_NOCHECK and if there are no "www" files the glob function will not return the pattern in the result array.